# Layer normalization Weight re-scaling and re-centering

Tags: deep-learning, linear-algebra, normalization, batch-normalization

In the paper on Layer normalization (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.06450.pdf) they say that

> layer normalization is invariant to scaling of the entire weight
> matrix and invariant to a shift to all of the incoming weights in the
> weight matrix

and then they prove it with the following:

[image]

I do not fully understand how they pass from 2nd to 3rd equality. Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

You have to be aware of two assumptions

One about the normalization

> under batch and weight normalization, if
> the weight vector is scaled by δ, the two scalar µ and σ will also be scaled by δ

This tells you that `δ/σ'=1/σ` then you eliminate the `δ` factor, and replace  `µ'` by `µ` and `σ'` by `σ`.
One about the relation between the two weight matrices

> Let there be two sets of model parameters θ, θ
> 0 whose weight matrices W and W'
> differ by a scaling factor δ and all of the incoming weights in W0
> are also shifted by a constant
> vector γ, that is W' = δW + 1γ^T

Notice that the `γ^Tx` is a scalar that depends on `x`, thus `γ^Tx`, and the term `1γ^Tx` will be compensated by `µ=µ'/δ - γ^Tx`.

Please forgive me eventual typos.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I Cannot understand why `µ=µ'/δ - γ^Tx`, i thought that  `µ = µ'/δ`. How can you infer that `µ=µ'/δ - γ^Tx`? Cheers!